# Parse Matrix from Textfile to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, matrix, arraylist

I am currently trying to parse content from textfile to a List in Java. But basically i got confused, because it doesn´t work like I would expect it.

Code:

```
if (charArray[i] == 'R') {
   ArrayList<Integer> C = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> T = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             for(int q = 0; q < input.geta()*6; q++) {
                 q++;
                 C.add((int) charArray[q+1]-48);
             }

   ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> C_C = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
   C_C.clear();
   int element = -1;
   for(int t = 0; t < C.size(); t++) {
       element++;
       if(element == input.geta()) {
          element = 0;
          System.out.println("add " + (ArrayList<Integer>) T);
          C_C.add((ArrayList<Integer>) T);
          T.clear();
        }
        T.add(C.get(t));
    }
    System.out.println("add " + (ArrayList<Integer>) T);
    C_C.add((ArrayList<Integer>) T);
    System.out.println("is " + C_C);
    input.setR(C_C);  
}
```

Output:

```
add [2, 0, 0, 1]
add [1, 0, 1, 0]
add [2, 1, 0, 0] 
is [[2, 1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0]]
```

My textfile contains: `R=2,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0` 
input.geta() is 4

My 3x4 Matrix should look like: 
2 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 
2 1 0 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating on the same `ArrayList` all the time.

Instead, you need create a new `ArrayList` every time and put it into `C_C`:

```
C_C.add(new ArrayList<>(T));
```

Comment: @ternes3 No problem. Glad to help :)